# Issue while opening Manage App Settings Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

While opening Manage App Settings page in android Xiaomi MI4 opens a black settings with displaying only app icons. Code I am using is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Is it working in other phones?

Comment: Yes, Its working fine on other devices

Comment: whats the tragetSdkVersion in your manifest?

Comment: Target SDK is 19 where as Mi4i is Android 5.0.2 version 21. Is this effect?

Comment: It happens, try to change it and then test

Comment: Android library i am using 4.4.2, Should i change it too..?

Comment: No, you don't need to change library.

Comment: But same working on other device i test it on nexsus 4(5.1)(22), and it opens right page..

Comment: os version of that phone?

Comment: Already mentioned 5.1  and even on moto g 5.0.2 its working fine

Comment: Might be its problem of this phone not of android version because its working so fine with me.

Comment: but when we manually open manage apps settings its opening fine